# Use typedefinition from other class in constructor of templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef

I am trying to make a class where the constructor takes in a parameter of a type corresponding to a typedefinition defined in the templated class.
Please see the following illustrational snippet which does not compile.

```
class A
{
    typedef enum test_t {
        a1,
        a2,
        a3
    } test_t;
};

template <class T>
class B
{
    B(T::test_t obj);
};

template <class T>
B<T>::B(T::test_t obj)
{

}

// Explicit definition to let compiler know a template instantiation
template class B<A>;
```

When compiling this code I get the following errors:

> TemplatedClassTest.cpp:13:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘obj’
>
> TemplatedClassTest.cpp:17:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Comment: `typename T::test_t`

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You need `B(typename T::test_t obj)` in both cases.

Comment: And also make `test_t` public.

Comment: All the members in your classes are private

Comment: Thank you. That did it!